# finding mean in original function (and other problems!)

Tags: php, function

Can someone fix my functions?

First, how can I go about getting the mean from my numbers that are used in the sum function? What varaible can I use to divide the numbers if I don't know how many numbers will be used?

Second, why isn't my find replace function working? When I run the string with the 'bad' words, i get this (i just entered ugly):

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "nice" }
```

I want the whole string returned with just the bad words replaced...

also, even tho its in there its not returning the length of the string and the number of words in the string! Grr...Pretty frustrated so i would be very grateful for any help...

File one: (to get the return of the functions)

```
    <?php
    require('myfunctions.php');
    if($_POST) {
    $result = phptest($_POST['input']);
    if ($result === false) {
    echo 'No rude words were found.';
    } else {
    var_dump($result);
    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    echo "<br/> Sum function:".sum(1,2,3,4)."<br/>";
    echo "Average function:".mean(1,2,3,4)."<br/>";
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input name="input" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

myfunctions:

```
    <?php
    function sum()
    {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<func_num_args(); $i++) $sum+= func_get_arg($i);
    return $sum;
    }

    ?>
    <?php
    function phptest($input) {
    $search = array('ugly', 'rude');
    $replace = array('nice', 'sweet');
    $output = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $input, $replace_count);
    if ($replace_count === 0) {
    return false;
    } else {
    return explode(' ', $output);
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: *What variable can I use to divide the numbers if I don't know how many numbers will be used?* But you know it, you already use a function to get the number: `func_num_args()`.

Comment: The search and replace is returning an array because of this `return explode(' ', $output);` if you want a string do this: `return $output;`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. It is preferred for you to ask individual questions separately. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Take advantage of PHP native functions, like [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) in combination with your `func_*` functions.

```
function sum() {
  return array_sum(func_get_args());
}

function avg() {
  $args = func_num_args();

  if ($args == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  return array_sum(func_get_args()) / $args;
}
```

As far as your `phptest()` function, see the comment by **Glass Robot**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the built-in PHP function `array_sum()` rather than rolling your own `sum()` function.

Lets say you have a set of numbers you want to work with. If you put them into an array, you can then use `array_sum()` to add them up, and `count()` to find out how many numbers there are.

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3,4);
echo "<br/> Sum function:".array_sum($data)."<br/>";
echo "Average function:".(array_sum($data) / count($data))."<br/>";
?>
```

If you *insist* on writing your own `mean()` function in the style of your existing `sum()` function, then you've already answered your own question by using the `func_num_args()`, which does exactly what you're asking for, and tells you how many arguments were passed into the function.

When it comes to your second question, I'll refrain for giving a direct answer, as the whole topic of profanity filters has been beaten to death on this site. It's generally considered to be an impossible problem to solve, as it's always easy to find ways around any filter, and they generally throw up false positives at the most unfortunate moments (even if your function worked, it would fall foul of the [Clubttic mistake](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html) . But if you insist on writing one, I'll direct you to this question here on SO, which has a good answer for PHP: [How do I replace bad words with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020451/how-do-i-replace-bad-words-with-php)

Hope that helps.